# Finding a function $\phi$ so that $\phi(X)$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

In my notes, Chebyshev's inequality is formulated as follows:
$$
\forall a \geq 0: P(X \geq a) \leq \dfrac{1}{\phi(a)}E[\phi(X)]
$$
Which is true when $X$ is a random variable and  $\phi\geq 0$ and non-decreasing for $-\infty < x < \infty$.

$\phi(X)$ is simply said to be a function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so that X is a random variable.

Which conditions apply so that $\phi(X)$ is still a random variable?

Comment: What sort of set is $\phi^{-1} ((-\infty, x])$?

Comment: A Borel algebra? I'm still not quite getting there

Comment: Well, if $X$ is measurable, then the composition will be. Sine $\phi$ is non decreasing, inverse images of intervals are intervals.

Comment: So $\phi$ could simply be $x$ or $e^x$? This makes little sense to me, since $E[\phi(X)]$ would be $\infty$

Comment: Why would the expectation be infinity?

Comment: Okay, that isn't true. I think I'm starting to grasp it now

Comment: Sorry but did you check the answer below, even minimally, before accepting it? (Which happened merely 24 minutes after it was posted.)

Comment: @StubbornAtom "it has to be continuous and strictly increasing so that it is invertible" No. No need for invertibility here.

Comment: @Did What if I don't want to invoke any measure-theoretic argument? The statement is of course a simplified one.

Comment: @StubbornAtom If the goal is to prove that $\phi(X)$ is a random variable, every argument will be, at least minimally, measure-theoretical... hence I fail to get the distinction you are trying to make. (But please do not confuse "simplified" and "misleading", these are *quite* different.)

Comment: @StubbornAtom Again: it is misleading to invoke continuity or convexity when both are quite unrelated to the result (only the sign and the monotonicity of phi are).

Comment: I spoke of convexity not to prove the question in the post , it was for Jensen's inequality. What I sense you are saying is that the continuity argument is 'unnecessary', but I wouldn't say it is misleading.

Comment: @StubbornAtom "What I sense you are saying" Sorry but there is no need to "sense" anything here, reading what I wrote from the start would suffice... (Or is this some kind of rhetorical tactics to avoid addressing squarely the points I make? Five unnecessary comments above already, and five others on your post below...)

Comment: @StubbornAtom Six now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Edited answer after realizing my mistake:*

The function $\phi$ only needs to be measurable for $\phi(X)$ to be a random variable. As @Did says, a non-decreasing function is trivially measurable.

More formally, if $X$ is a random variable defined on  $(\Omega,\mathscr A)$, then for any Borel (measurable) function $\phi$ on $\mathbb R$, $\phi(X)$ is also a random variable.

This is because for all $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $$\{\omega\in\Omega:\phi(X(\omega))\le x\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in \phi^{-1}((-\infty,x])\}$$

As $\phi$ is measurable, $\phi^{-1}((-\infty,x])$ is a Borel (measurable) set and as $X$ is a random variable, $$\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in \phi^{-1}((-\infty,x])\}\in \mathscr A\quad,\forall\,x\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: Continuity and being strictly increasing are off-topic. Every nondecreasing function is trivially measurable. Likewise, convexity/concavity are not needed for the desired inequality to hold.

Comment: @Did I had checked my sources before I posted anything. It might be the case that the argument isn't rigorous or it might be a particular case of the general argument, but I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Do you read the word "wrong" in my comment? The trouble with your post is akin to stating that a function must be polynomial to be continuous...

Comment: @Did For the record, I addressed the main question by providing a particular function $g$, not *all* functions for which the statement is true. And for this $g$, it has to be invertible and continuity+strictly increasing takes care of that.

Comment: For the record, this is not what the OP is asking. (Although I would agree that the fact that they accept an answer not addressing their own question somewhat muddies things... but this is a phenomenon we are accustomed to on the site, alas, is it not?)

Comment: The first paragraph of StubbornAtom's answer answered my question. That's why I accepted it. I admit that my understanding of the subject isn't sufficient to add to your discussion about the possibly misleading nature of the answer.

Comment: @Did However, if you feel that StubbornAtom's answer is insufficient or unclear, I invite you to write one yourself, to show the point you're making.

Comment: @SimonKrekels ?? What for, since you accepted this (misleading and not addressing the question) answer? Yes this is a strange world...

Comment: Always amusing to see retreats to appeals to subjectivity regarding matters in which, by essence, objectivity should rule.

Comment: @Did I accepted it, but since you comment that it is not a good answer, I assumed you had something to add. Is there a way to close this question, since I don't think anyone is gaining from this anymore?

Comment: @SimonKrekels Wait, this is **your** problem if you accept answers without understanding them, right? How am I even involved?